# DBAdapter inserting data

Tags: java, android, sqlite, insert

I got my DBAdapter.java where I create DB, etc.. and I got the following (when I call this it should had data into the DB):

```
public long insertRow(String valorglicemico, String datahora) { 

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_VALORGLICEMICO, valorglicemico);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATAHORA, datahora);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
```

Now, on my mainActivity it's where  I call the previous stuff and I have a button that is waiting for something:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diab2014_activity_1);           


        // enable the home button
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);          

    value = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        

     public void onClick(View v) { 

                     String a = value.getText().toString();
                     String b = "";

                     myDB.insertRow(a,  b);
                }
    });
```

LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1267): Process: com.example.project, PID: 1267
E/AndroidRuntime(1267): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.example.projdiab2014.Diab2014Activity_1$1.onClick(mainActivity.java:53)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Did I forget something?

Comment: Yes, you forgot to format the code so we do not get headache while reading it ;-)

Comment: do you mean the LogCat? The last part are the errors

Comment: Did you declare value and btn1, before using them? The code is not shown.

Comment: In particular, `btn1` doesn't seem to have a `findViewById` before assigning a Click Listener to it. I'd like to see the complete onCreate method.

Comment: it have, but isnt on that code. Every variable is declared. I think the problem its between the 2 classes, some communication prob

Comment: Where have you initialized myDB?

Comment: I think its that. called openDB(); on method on create. Create 'private void openDB() {
  myDB = new DBAdapter(this);
  myDB.open();
 }'

Comment: Now, im not sure how i should had on the variable b the current time

Comment: What is the code for `insertRow()`?

Comment: myDB is null, or you have declared it somewhere not accessible by the method?

Answer (score 0):

Here do you define myDb? Database should get a context parameter but I can't see the definiton. It might be a your problem.Also always use try catch while doing db operations. Here an example of defining a database helper and inserting a record to table.I tried code and it is working.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String TAG = "db";
public static final int VERSION = 1;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "mydb", null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + "MY_TABLE"
            + " (NAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + "SURNAME TEXT);");
}

public long insertRow(String valorglicemico, String datahora) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    long retval = 0;
    try {
        initialValues.put("NAME", valorglicemico);
        initialValues.put("SURNAME", datahora);
        retval = db.insert("MY_TABLE", null, initialValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "insertRow exception", e);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
    return retval;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

And on the activity class

```
dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    String a = name.getText().toString();
    String b = "";
    long val = dbHelper.insertRow(a, b);
    Log.d("DB", val+"");
    }
});
```